# Is it worth buying paid mount in WoW?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am very casual gamer when it comes to WoW. I rarely play this game and I get really bored many times when it comes to traveling far distances. I thinking of buying premium mounts from the store to save time.

I did not find any extra information other than the price. This is what I want to know about these mounts.

- Swift Windsteed
- Armored Bloodwing
- Winged Guardian
- Heart of the Aspects
- Celestial Steed

---

1. Can I use them immediately? irrespective of level? I am now level 23
2. Speed of these mounts?
3. Is it tradable? or bound?

1 and 2 are very important for me.

Comment: Sadly, buying a mount from the store will not allow you to save time. Mount speed is based on your personal mounted speed (via training), not the mount itself.

Comment: @Koviko Haven't played WoW ever since Burning Crusade. Back then, mount speed was based on your mount + gear (carrot on a stick and/or boots with mythril spores). When did the mount system change, Cataclysm?

Comment: Yes. The change was made in patch 4.0.1, Cataclysm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is been a while since I played Wow, but i remember buying the celestial steed :
http://eu.blizzard.com/store/details.xml?id=221003877

According to the info it sais:

> so saddle up, because this supernatural warhorse will fly as fast as your riding skill will take you, and it will travel at 310% speed if you have at least one other 310% mount. 
>   Once activated, this in-game pet key applies to all present and future World of Warcraft characters on a single European or Russian Battle.net account.

So your answers are:

1. Yes as long as you have a riding skill (lvl 20 minimum).
2. They scale according to your riding skill so if you have 90% run speed then that is the max you can get. If you are lvl 80 and have 310% flying speed then that is the speed they will have.
3. They are bound, but you get them for every character you create.

In short, the store mounts are purely cosmetic.  They will not get you higher speed sooner than the regular mounts.

Comment: aren't all mounts shared between characters now?

Comment: @Kreiri All normal mounts are shared account wide.  Class-specific mounts (Paladin/Warlock) are limited to their classes/races, and some faction-specific mounts get converted.  For example, if you have the [Grand Armored Gryphon](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=135416) on an Alliance character, you'll automatically (no rep or purchase required) get the [Grand Armored Wyvern](http://www.wowhead.com/item=93169) on any Horde characters you have.

Answer (score 1):

As above, you can purchase store mounts, but you still need to spend gold at the flying trainer to get the speed increase.

I have various characters on different server accumulated over time, mounts are account wide (with some limitations), so if you spend some cash, then join a friend on another server you'll still have it, but if you level a new character, purchase flying, then sadly, no, you won't get getting the 310% speed.

**Short answer**: No, it's won't save you time, but it might make it less tedious if you have to look at a nice mount instead of a boring gryphon etc.